# Given a subset $S$, is there any universal construction (property) of $L(S)$, the linear span of $S$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, category-theory, span, universal-property

Given a subset $S$ of a vector space $V$, is there any universal construction (property) of $L(S)$, the linear span of $S$ (like the way we can construct  the fraction field of an integral domain)?

Comment: what definition of span do you use? if i am not mistaken the definition gives you already a construction.
There is also a non-constructive definition for the span, that is the intersection of all subspaces containing S (i know this def. as "hull")

Comment: @supinf: I use the set of all finite linear combinations of the elements of $S$ as the definition of $L(S)$ . How does that already give a universal construction ? I cannot see the map...

Comment: ok maybe i misunderstood what you want with universal construction.

Answer (score 3):

The span of $S$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that contains $S$ as a subset.

If you want something that look more categorical, we can say that whenever $W$ is a vector space and $f:S\to W$ is a map that respects linear combinations in the sense that $a_1s_1+\cdots+a_ns_n=0$ implies $a_1f(s_1)+\cdots+a_nf(s_n)=0$, then $f$ extends so a linear transformation $L(S)\to W$ in exactly one way. And $L(S)$ is the only subspace of $V$ that has this property.

Comment: More precisely, it is the smallest subspace of $V$ whose underlying set contains $S$. Vector spaces and other algebraic structures should not be confused with their underlying sets (although this is done all the time).

Answer (score 3):

If $S$ is linearly independent, then $L(S)$ is the free vector space on $S$, i.e. we have the universal property $\hom(L(S),W) \cong \hom(S,|W|)$ for vector spaces $W$; here $|W|$ denotes the underlying set. If $S$ is arbitrary, you cannot really specify a universal property of $L(S)$ inside the category of vector spaces directly. We know from linear algebra that $S$ contains a linearly independent subset $S'$ which still generates $L(S)$, and $L(S)=L(S')$ is the free vector space on $S'$. For a universal property inside the partial order of subspaces of $V$ (which you may regard as a thin category), see the answer by Henning Makholm.

Answer (score 2):

$L(S)$ is the image of the map $F(S)\to V$ induced by the universal property from the inclusion $S\hookrightarrow V$ ($F(S)$ being the free vector space spanned by $S$). the image of a map itself is defined as the kernel of the cokernel, which both are described by universal properties.
for example, the kernel of $f:V\to W$ is an object $V'$ with a map $i:V'\to V$ (nessecarily monomorphism) such that for every $g:U\to V$ with $fg=0$, $g$ factors through $i$. the cokernel is defined dually.
I don't know if it's possible to encapsulate all these three construction in one.